# Luna OS Overheating/ how to install TLP

Tags: power-management, elementary-os

I have a problem regarding overheating with my newly installed Elementary OS Luna. This used to happen before, when i was using Ubuntu, as well as on Linux Mint. On earlier versions of Ubuntu I used Jupiter, and then on later versions transferred to TLP.

Does anyone know what to type in Luna OS terminal in order to install TLP and manage heat?

Answer (score 1):

[Several](http://sourcedigit.com/20523-improve-battery-life-in-linux-install-tlp-on-ubuntu-16-04/) [random](http://www.2daygeek.com/things-to-do-after-installing-elementary-os-0-4-loki-post-installation-guide-tweaks/2/) [sources](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-tlp-0-5-on-ubuntu-14-0413-1012-1012-04-linux-mint-17161413-and-elementary-os-0-2/) I got from DuckDuckGo claim the following is the desired procedure (for Elementary OS Luna and Freya and Loki):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

And if you're not doing a restart, but want to turn it on manually/right_away:

```
$ sudo tlp start
```